# retrieving data from postgresql database into a dictionary in django

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to return data that was retrieved from the database into a dictionary

view.py

```
from django.db import connection


def custom_query(query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row
```

when I try and change `fetchall()` to `dictfetchall()` it says `'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute 'dictfetchall'`
I have tried also to add an argument in the cursor method `cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor` it says `cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cursor_factory'`

Comment: I find it rather weird that you use cursors, instead of the django ORM.

Comment: Because I will be using complex queries that i am not used to create them with django ORM

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions you can use [`NamedTupleCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#namedtuple-cursor), [`DictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor), or [`RealDictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor):

Import:

```
from psycopg2.extras import NamedTupleCursor
```

As the default cursor on the connection:

```
psycopg2.connect(dsn, cursor_factory=NamedTupleCursor)
```

Or per query:

```
with connection.cursor(cursor_factory=NamedTupleCursor) as cursor:
    cursor.execute('select * from tbl')

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row.col1, row.col2)
```

Comment: so what is the dsn and how do i find it?

Comment: e.g.: `psycopg2.connect(dbname='test', user='postgres', password='secret', ...)`

Comment: now it says 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'execute'